# Заполнить массив случайными числами, каждое из которых встретится 2 раза

Tags: delphi, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть массив целых чисел на 24 значений, названный pole. Нужно заполнить его числами от 1 до 12, чтобы каждое число повторялось 2 раза. При этом, числа должны быть "вразброс". Как реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот один из возможных вариантов решения вашей задачи

```
     pole : array [1..24] of integer;
procedure peretasovka;
    var
    sl:TstringList;
    i:integer;
    begin
    sl:=tstringlist.Create;
    for i := 0 to 23 do   sl.Add(IntTostr(i div 2+1));    // Заполнили список парами чисел последовательно
    for i := 0 to 23 do  sl.Exchange(i,random(sl.Count)); // Перетасовали список
    for i := 0 to 23 do  pole[i+1]:=StrToInt( sl.Strings[i]);// Перенесли со списка в массив
    sl.Free;
    end;
```

Comment: круто, вначале числа преобразовали в строки, а потом назад в числа:) Прям как в анекдоте о том, как закипятить чайник с водой, если он уже с водой.

Comment: это всё наверное для того, чтоб красиво заюзать sl.Exchange, вместо перемещения числового значения по рандомному индексу )

Comment: согласен что не тру, но это тоже вариант, а во вторых студенту проще будет разобраться.

Чем больше будет выходить не образованных дельфистов тем выше я буду ценится :)

Comment: мне хорошие делфи программисты не вредят.

Answer (score 8):

Эта задача решается так. Вначале массив заполняется нужными числами (в любом удобном порядке, например 1, 1, 2, 2, .. 12, 12), а потом к нему применяется алгоритм с названием shuffle (тасовать). На делфи есть варианты реализации. Вот две реализации для массивов и коллекций. Остальное найдете в гугле по запросу "delphi shuffle" или в книгах Кнута.

- [How to shuffle array values](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip1003_4.htm)
- [How to Randomize / Shuffle Collections and Lists](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/list_randomize.htm)

Answer (score 3):

```
type
  TIntArray24 = array [0..23] of Integer;

function GetPole: TIntArray24;

  procedrue Exchange(var I1, I2: Integer);
  var
    tmp: Integer;
  begin
    tmp := I1;
    I1 := I2;
    I2 := tmp;
  end;

var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Result) to High(Result) do 
    Result[I] := (I + 2) div 2;  // +2 если масив от нуля, а цифры нужны от 1
  for I := Low(Result) to High(Result) do
    Exchangle(Result[I], 
      Result[Random(High(Result) - Low(Result)) + Low(Result)]); // махинации с Low High нужны чтобы не менять код когда меняется длина массива
end;
```